# Search and Matching model with 2 agents?

Tags: macroeconomics, unemployment, dsge, search-and-matching, heterogeneity

I would like to know if you know any model with Search and matching framework (Mortenses-Pisarides style) with 2 types of workers (like Ricardian and rule of thumb consumers for exemple) ? I would like to see such a model featuring different wages, hours worked and unemployment rates between the 2 consumers. In the end I would like to implement such a framework to a DSGE model with Ricardian and rule of thumb consumers. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean two types of workers?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: I'm not sure about exactly two, but if you google "mortensen pissarides heterogeneous workers," many papers show up.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but this paper has model that sounds like what you want:

[Shimer, Robert, 2006. “On-the-job search and strategic bargaining, ”European EconomicReview50, 811—830.](http://home.uchicago.edu/shimer/wp/dispersion.pdf)

Have a look at this one too:

[Shimer, R. (2007). Mismatch. American Economic Review, 97(4), 1074-1101.](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.97.4.1074)